# Pyspark to change values

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column label:

```
label
  0
  1
  2
  3
  0
```

And I want to create a new column `new_label`  changing all values that is not `3` to `0`.
to have only 2 classes: `0` and `3`

I am pretty new to pyspark.  How can I do this?

Comment: you want an UDF or you want the good-practice way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming df is your dataframe :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("new_label", F.when(F.col("label") == 3, 3).otherwise(0))
```